# JPA - Many To One relationship not working

Tags: jpa

I m having a problem with JPA ManyToOne relationship. I have two entities (HikeList, User):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_HIKELIST")
public class Hikelist implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "login", referencedColumnName = "login")
    private User user;
...
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 0, max = 50)
    @Id
    private String login;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<Hikelist> hikeListCollection;
 ...
}
```

My test class :

```
   ...
    @Test
    public void testCreateUser() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setLogin("thomaslogin");
        user.setEmail("thomas@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword("thomas");
        user.setFirstName("thomas");
        user.setLastName("thomas");
        userService.createUser(user);

        Hikelist hike = new Hikelist();
        hike.setId(new Long(1L));
        hike.setLabel("GR20");
        hike.setUser(user);
        hikeService.createHikeList(hike);

        Hikelist hike1 = hikeRepository.findOne(new Long(1L));
        assertNotNull(hike1);
    }
```

I m getting the following error when I m calling : hikeService.createHikeList(hike);

Does anybody know where I am wrong?
Thank you in advance.

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not
>   commit JPA transaction; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the
>   transaction   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:524)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
>     at
>   com.breizh.packlight.service.HikelistService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$38379214.createHikeList()
>     at
>   com.breizh.packlight.service.HikelistServiceTest.testCreateUser(HikelistServiceTest.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
>   Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing
>   the transaction   at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:515)
>     ... 37 more Caused by: javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException:
>   HV000030: No validator could be found for type:
>   com.breizh.packlight.domain.User.     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.verifyResolveWasUnique(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:218)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.findMatchingValidatorClass(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:193)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorManager.getInitializedValidator(ConstraintValidatorManager.java:97)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:478)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:424)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:340)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:158)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:137)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:206)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
>     ... 38 more

Answer (score 1):

The error is:

```
javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for type: com.breizh.packlight.domain.User
```

And it's caused by

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
private User user;
```

How can a User have a size between 1 and 50?

Validation constraints apply the the Java objects. Not to the columns in the database. You already make sure that the login is of the right size, and the user field is mapped to a column which has a foreign key constraint, so the `@Size` annotation here is not only not working, but unnecessary.

Comment: I kept reading my code again and again to find a dummy mistake and couldn't find it.Thanks a lot for opening my eyes...